# Should extremely long tags be shortened?

Tags: discussion, tags

Apparently, if tags wrap to a second line in a question listing, the "recent activity by" div gets pushed down an extra line.

[Unusually wide gap if tags wrap to next line in question listing http://img710.imageshack.us/img710/9334/biggap.png](http://img710.imageshack.us/img710/9334/biggap.png)

Comment: I haven't heard that phrase since I had braces.

Comment: Uuh... and and the problem with this is... what? Something that spanned two lines took up, oh gosh, two lines!

Comment: @Farseeker, it's unnecessarily attention-grabbing.

Comment: I doubt it was done on purpose...

Comment: @Farseeker, I'm not saying the user did it on purpose, I'm just saying there is no reason his question should stick out from all the others.

Answer (score 2):

I'd say somebody needs to use shorter tags. I mean, `webdeploymentproject`? `badimageformatexception`?

Comment: BadImageFormatException is a built-in .net type, so it's OK (if exception names are generally ok as tags) - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.badimageformatexception.aspx

Comment: But if you use really long tag names, you get rewarded by having the widest, most attention-grabbing question on the page.

Comment: @Michael didn't know that, that makes it okay. Still, the other ones don't make sense. @DanM true!

Answer (score 0):

Regardless of the length of the tags, I don't think the question is any more rewarded for being *the most attention-grabbing question on the page*. If someone were interested in those tags, they're gonna read the question. And, too, if the question is poorly written, then the alleged *reward* won't be so great.

I don't see a problem with the extra gap, either.

I do agree, however, that the tags are extremely long. Why not shorten the tags when not describing a specific built-in type (as @Michael Stum points out)? For instance:

1. `webapplicationproject` -> `webappl-proj`
2. `webdeploymentproject` -> `webdeploy-proj`

These are just off the top of my head, but I think they are a reasonable place to start.

Even still, BadImageFormatException can be shortened to an accepted abbreviation: `BadImageFormatExc`.

Comment: I'm definitely not defending the tags used in that example, I was just browsing the question listing and thought this question stuck out from all the others by being *way* wider. But I guess I'm the only one who thinks this is a problem.